# hadoop daemons not starting

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, java, hadoop

I have followed [this](https://data-flair.training/blogs/installation-of-hadoop-3-on-ubuntu/) tutorial to install hadoop on an Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual Machine (4 cores and 10 gb of ram) with learning purposes. I have successfully followed all the steps without any errors. These are all my configuration files:

[core-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUGf2.png)

[hdfs-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFACA.png)

[yarn-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FbhH.png)

[mapred-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uirMf.png)

the `hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format` command works as expected.

The problem is when starting `dfs` and `yarn` services, the commands `hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh` and `hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh` don't show any errors, but when I do `jps`, `datanode` and `resource manager` are missing.

[datanode log](https://pastebin.com/EZxqKFvJ)

datanode out

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 39570
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 39570
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/home/kevin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.52.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

[Resource manager log](https://pastebin.com/Jjzh07AW)

Resource manager out

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/home/kevin/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 39570
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 39570
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:28 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:28 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebServices as a root resource class
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:28 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:28 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:28 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
```

[Node manager log](https://pastebin.com/3yadhttR)

Node manager out

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 39570
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 39570
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/home/kevin/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:31 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.NMWebServices as a root resource class
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:31 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:31 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:31 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Oct 24, 2019 2:35:31 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
```

Tried also stopping and re-running with `hadoop/sbin/stop-all.sh` and `hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh`  but still not working.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I would edit the question and expand the section "_but when I do_ `jps`, `datanode` _and_ `resource manager` _are missing_" so that the readers become able to understand where the Software Faults are residing and what Error Messages or what Log Files they are producing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, logs added to the question.